# Haskell do keyword

Tags: haskell

So I've been working on this problem of printing out a Sudoku board for the past couple hours and I'm almost finished but I'm stuck at the final step. So what I have is a Sudoku board represented as a "list of lists" (i.e. board = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5, ...], ...]

I've been able to print out a line with formatting with the following function:

```
line i s_board = intercalate " | " . map unwords . chunksOf 3 $ map show a
             where 
               a = s_board!!i
```

So by making a call like "line 0 board" i would get "1 3 5 | 7 0 2 | 0 0 0" which is partially what I need. Next I tried to use a "do block" to output the board that I need which looked something like this:

```
print = do line 0 board 
        line 1 board 
        ...
```

This wouldn't even compile, and when I did something like this:

```
print = do 
        line 0 board 
        line 1 board
```

The appropriate list was printed multiple times which is fairly confusing. I wanted to work my way up to including extra formatting such as printing a string such as "----------" after every three lines to complete the board but I can't even get the other thing to work right yet. I'd appreciate any help offered with these issues.

Comment: Show minimal but complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @melpomene What else should I include? The only thing that I left out was the definition of the board at the top of my file. I have the function "line" defined and then the other things were failed attempts.

Comment: *Complete* means code I can run and test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be easier and more elegant to produce a function that takes your
board, makes one big string, and finally prints it, rather than worrying about
printing every line via a `do` block.

So, if we simplify your line showing function to take one line of the board:

```
showLine :: [Int] -> String
showLine = intercalate " | "
         . map unwords
         . chunksOf 3
         . map show
```

Then, we need to get the string representation of each line and put them all
together. This looks pretty much like the `showLine` code:

```
showBoard :: [[Int]] -> String
showBoard = intercalate "---------------------\n"
          . map unlines
          . chunksOf 3
          . map showLine
```

Using the example board

```
-- Obviously not a valid sudoku board...
example :: [[Int]]
example = replicate 9 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

*Main> putStrLn $ showBoard example
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
---------------------
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
---------------------
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original attempt didn't compile because it violates Haskell's layout rules.

The second didn't do what you expect because `line n board` is a list, so the `do`-notation means nondeterminism, not sequencing of IO actions.  If you tried to put a type like

```
print :: IO ()
```

above your function (incidentally, `print` is defined in the Standard Prelude and you should be getting a warning about shadowing it), the type-checker would inform you of your mistake.  If you really wanted to print out the board like this (although as the other answer suggests, building a string and then printing this whole thing out is much better), you could try

```
printBoard :: IO ()
printBoard = do print $ line 0 board
                print $ line 1 board
```

or to print the whole board,

```
printBoard = mapM_ (print . showLine) board
```

where `showLine` is like your `print` but with the indexing stripped out.